# How do I get Internet Explorer to do a better job displaying images

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-9

On the left is chrome, on the right is IE9, same image, same html, but one of them looks like utter crap.  How do I get IE to not screw up my images?

[image: Image Display Problem]

Here is the actual image being displayed in the page, in case that helps

[image: Actual image used to create the screenshot above]

Here is the html:

```
<div id="logo-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default" style="height: 80px; width: 950px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<img src="/static/img/logo.gif" height="40"><a id="logout" href="/viewer/logout">Logout</a>
<div id="logo-clearEl" class="x-clear" role="presentation">
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the css for the img tag

```
#logo-body img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.x-border-box, .x-border-box * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
fieldset, img {
    border: 0;
}
```

and the css for the parent div

```
#logo-body {
  border: none;
}
#logo, #logo-body {
  background-color: #002d56;
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, cover, #008dc6, #002d56 68%);
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, cover, #008dc6, #002d56 68%);
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(50% 50%, cover, #008dc6, #002d56 68%);
  background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 50%, cover, #008dc6, #002d56 68%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(50% 50%, cover, #008dc6, #002d56 68%);
}
.x-panel-body-default {
  background: white;
  border-color: #99bce8;
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.x-panel-body-default {
  background: white;
  border-color: #99bce8;
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.x-panel-body {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.x-border-box, .x-border-box * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a css gradient as the background?

Comment: Actually seeing your html and css would be useful, so we can determine if you are using features that are unsupported or only partially supported in IE9.

Comment: Have you tried removing the gradients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to this is that you can't.  IE is just an inferior browser in almost every regard, and it shows more and more, from image rendering to debugging, to css support, you name it.

Converting to PNG from GIF did nothing, creating a whole new logo does solve the problem, but doesn't really answer the question.  Someday IE will cease to exist (I hope) and we will no longer spend more time making up for its deficiencies than we do creating whole products.

To those of you that helped create IE, a curse upon you and all your descendants.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the image itself, You can try saving it as a PNG rather that a GIF.

> PNG generally produces better-looking images with smaller file sizes than GIF for the same kinds...[More](http://www.digitalfamily.com/tutorials/whats-the-best-image-format-for-the-web/)

Or re-create the image and use a different file format. Like this:
[image: logo]

for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Wy8Y4/8/

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbEug.png" height="40"><a id="logout" href="/viewer/logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: +1 This is a great example of when it's appropriate to use PNG over GIF with transparency.

Comment: Converting my image to PNG doesn't seem to help at all.  Your new Image is much better, probably due to no italics and maybe you are better with the graphical tools than I.  I'm considering changing logo to just use text and let it be drawn by the font engine, that way I should be able to get Italics and get it without the image problems.  I can add the shadow on good browsers and just let IE continue to look plain, but at least it won't be so ugly.